# I am in an online “relationship “ with a girl but don’t know if it’s halal?

Tags: halal-haram, nikah, relationships

So this new Muslim whom I met online and I plan to marry but we don’t know if it would happen due to fear of my parents not accepting due to culture . We are both young (20 and 18)
And would like to know if this is halal Thing to do? Is it halal to joke about (not about Islam but like teasing each other ) but also be serious and teach about Islam but plan to marry even though it’s not official or anything? Like is it
Halal
?

Answer (score 1):

No this is not halal you must stop this relationship for the sake of Allah and repent and Allah Insha’Allah will forgive you.

Comment: But we plan to marry the halal way but we are unsure and aren’t saying I love you and whatever

Comment: @Cookie6788 either way. Islam prohibits a male from talking to a female (and vice versa) in secret/public/whatever the case may be. It is said that the third person is Shaytan.

Comment: @Epistemophile.Bibliophile that's not 100% true Islam prohibits being alone with a person from the opposite gender who is a non-Mahram. The prohibition to talk in public comes from you.

Comment: @Medi1Saif Islam doesn't allow free mixing between the opposite gender. That's been established already. Males cannot freely talk with the opposite gender nor hang out with them and vice versa.

Comment: Jazakallahu khairan for your advice . Please pray for my guidance and Allah accepts my duas.

Comment: @Epistemophile.Bibliophile that is true, but there's no free mixing in public and saying freely talking with the opposite gender is misleading as there are limitations however it is permissible.